# How to work with Selector Listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, selector, android-relativelayout

I have file **lst_custom_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@drawable/list_choose"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And Listview in **Main.xml**

```
<ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lstView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:divider="@drawable/menu_phancach"
                    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
                    android:visibility="visible">
         </ListView>
```

I use Selector with Background of Relativelayout with name **list_choose.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/menu_content" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/menu_content_hover" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/menu_content_hover" />
</selector>
```

it's show me the background of RelativeLayout menu_content_hover when i Press on items listview, but not selected with background menu_content_hover. I want it change background menu_content_hover when user press on items and **selected** ,change backround menu_content when user scroll list(unselected) or choose another items.I used simpleCursorAdapter. Any Help? Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The selector should be like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_focused" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_default"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: HI. Thanks for your help but it doesn't work. Because **state_focused** and **state_selected** don't thow the event. any other help